# How to sign copyright form in ManuscriptCentral website

Tags: copyright

Does anybody know how can I sign the copyright form in ManuscriptCentral website?

The portal provided an online form as the copyright form to sign.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write your name and surname in the signature field, and select the date. That's it.